# Find the shortest match between two occurrences of a pattern

Tags: regex, python-re

I'm using the pattern `\\n(((?!\.g).)*?\.vcf\.gz)\\r` to match the desired sub-string in a string. In the following example string the match is in the middle of the string, engulfed by two `\r\n`.

```
"\r\n1115492_23181_0_0.g.vcf.gz.tbi\r\n1115492_23181_0_0.vcf.gz\r\n1115492_23181_0_0.vcf.gz.tbi\r\n..."
```

Using the pattern above yields the desired string `1115492_23181_0_0.vcf.gz` as well as `0`.
My question is what would be the proper regular expression to get only the desired string.
Thanks.

Comment: `"\r\n"` is a CRLF ending, it is not a four character string. Use `(?m)^(?:(?!\.g).)*\.vcf\.gz$`, see https://regex101.com/r/HspcJL/2

Comment: The pattern didn't work with `\r\n`, so I used escape characters.

Comment: So, does my suggestion work?

Comment: It works on the link you posted but not in python.

Comment: I see, the CRLF ending is to blame. So you need `re.search(r"(?m)^(?:(?!\.g).)*\.vcf\.gz\r?$", text)`, see https://ideone.com/ScVaUC

Comment: It gets the result but with `\r`, so I added parentheses: `re.findall('((?m)^(?:(?!\.g).)*\.vcf\.gz)\r?$', string)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the match equalling lines, so match the whole lines that do not contain `.g` anywhere before the `.vcf.gz` extension:

```py
import re
text = "\r\n1115492_23181_0_0.g.vcf.gz.tbi\r\n1115492_23181_0_0.vcf.gz\r\n1115492_23181_0_0.vcf.gz.tbi\r\n..."
m = re.search(r"^((?:(?!\.g).)*\.vcf\.gz)\r?$", text, re.M)
if m:
    print(m.group(1)) # => 1115492_23181_0_0.vcf.gz
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ScVaUC).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `((?:(?!\.g).)*\.vcf\.gz)` - Group 1:

  - `(?:(?!\.g).)*` - any char other than line break chars, one or more but as many as possible occurrences, that does not start a `.g` char sequence
  - `\.vcf\.gz` - a `.vcf.gz` string
- `\r?` - an optional CR (carriage return)
- `$` - end of a line.